# an exit or go back button for lightbox

Tags: javascript, styles, lightbox

I have four thumbnails, and when you select one of the thumbnails, the picture enlarges into a box
But i am having a problem with getting out of that "box" or going back to just the four thumbnails and i want to have a like X or a exit button so you can go back or get rid of the box, all the code i have tried isn't working, i am new to this so sorry if this is a stupid question!

```
    <!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
<title> Light Box</title>
<h1> My Page </h1>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

function lightBox(imgNumber){
    var img = document.getElementById('changeImg');
    img.src = imgNumber;

    document.getElementById('BG').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('FG').style.display = "block";

}

</script>
<body>

<div id="BG" onClick="Box():">

</div>


<div id="FG">
    <img src="pic1.jpg" id="changeImg">
</div>


<div id="thumb">
    <img alt="Caption 1" src="pic1thumbnail.jpg" onClick="lightBox('pic1.jpg');" class="sty">
    <img alt="Caption 2" src="pic2thumbnail.jpg" onClick="lightBox('pic2.jpg');" class="sty">
    <img alt="Caption 3" src="pic3thumbnail.jpg" onClick="lightBox('pic3.jpg');" class="sty">
    <img alt="Caption 4" src="pic4thumbnail.jpg" onClick="lightBox('pic4.jpg');" class="sty">

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

this is my code ^

and this is my styling

```
body{
background-color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}



p {
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 100px;
}

#thumb{
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
color: black;
}

.sty {
padding-right: 10px;
}

#FG{
display: none;
border: 1px solid white;
background-color: white;
height: 350px;
width: 400px;
margin-left: -280px;
margin-top: -200px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: fixed;
padding: 10px;
}

#BG {
width: 100%;
height: 3000px;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
opacity: 0.8;
-moz-opacity:0.8;
-webkit-opacity:0.8;
display: none;
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code a bit. Can you try this?

http://jsfiddle.net/k2a3t18z/

```
function closeLightBox(){

    document.getElementById('BG').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('FG').style.display = "none";

}
```

---

```
<div id="FG">
    <div id="xbutton" class="xbutton" onclick="closeLightBox();">XXX</div> <br/>
    <img src="pic1.jpg" id="changeImg"/>
</div>
```

---

```
.xbutton{
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```